# Detect and remove empty directories from list

Tags: shell-script, directory, git

A common problem game developers have with the Unity3D engine and Git is that Unity and Git fight for whether an empty directory should exist or not - Git doesn't care, Unity3D will keep making git trackable *.meta files for empty directories. Basically means devs have to manually find and delete directories and meta files if a commit is made removing files and directories.

I'd like to create a Git post-checkout hook to trigger a directory removal when Git deletes files.

I have made a good start on it - I know what I need Git to do. But I'm not great with shell scripting and I'm struggling to make it work efficiently and correctly.

The main issue I'm having is that I just cannot get this line right:

```
dirs_to_check="($changed_files | xargs dirname | xargs sort -u)"
```

I was hoping it'd pipe each line into dirname, then take the whole list and remove dupes.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script will be run by Git after a checkout.

# --- Command line
oldRev="$1"
newRev="$2"
isBranchCheckout="$3"

# Grab a list of deleted files:
changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --diff-filter=D --no-commit-id $oldRev $newRev)"
# Just testing:
##changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id f5865290 eb793b0c)"

# Early exit if there are no removed files at all:
if [ -z "$changed_files" ]; then
    echo "No empty dirs"
    exit 0
fi

echo "$changed_files"
# Get the list of dir paths and then sort and remove dupes: 
dirs_to_check="($changed_files | xargs dirname | xargs sort -u)"

# For each dir check if its empty and if so, remove it:
# TODO: What about the case where the parent dir is also empty of files?
for dir in $dirs_to_check; do
    if [ "$(ls -A $dir)" ]; then
        echo "$dir Not Empty"
    else
        echo "$dir Empty"
        rm $dir
    fi
done
```

Here is some sample **changed_files** text if you want to test more easily:

```
test/with dir spaces/debrief/css/style.css
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/debrief/debrief.html
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/debrief/debrief_specification.js
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/debrief/js/debrief.js
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/debrief/js/debrief_specification.js
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/Loading.css
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/Loading.html
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/LoadingDLC1.html
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/HoG-logo.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/background_unused.jpg
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/banner-patch-1_4.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/bg-back.jpg
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/bg-front_unused.jpg
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/bg-front_unused.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/bg-logo.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/dlc1/bg-back.jpg
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/dlc1/bg-logo.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/dlc1/load-bar-empty.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/dlc1/load-bar-full.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/load-bar-empty.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/load-bar-full.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/loading-background.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/loading-background_unused.jpg
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/random_loading_pics/Ld0.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/random_loading_pics/Ld1.png
WFTO/uiresources/wftoUI/loading/images/random_loading_pics/Ld10.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant

```
dirs_to_check="$(echo "$changed_files" | xargs dirname | sort -u)"
```

A simple solution, unless you have thousands of directories, is simply to try to `rmdir` each directory and ignore the errors.

```
find . -depth -type d -exec echo rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} +
```

Change `.` to the top of the directories concerned. If your rmdir doesnt have the ignore option just redirect `2>/dev/null` to not have the warnings.

Comment: Thanks I'll give your changes a go. Re `find` - Its really important that it is efficient, so if I can use `find` to check specific directories and their parents that'd be great. I can't afford to run `find` on the entire project each time.

Comment: Damn. Either `xargs` or `dirname` cannot handle path lines with spaces in them. Maybe I need to use `for` and bash arrays?

Comment: Add `-d '\n' ` to xargs to cope with the spaces. Does your `changed_files` variable have many files per line?

Comment: Great that worked! `changed_files` will only have 1 `my/path to/file/filename.blah` per line, as per the sample posted above. Now that I have a list of empty dirs, would you have any suggestions on one would check parent dir if it too is empty of files, recursively? I will fall back to just writing a recursive function if not.

Comment: You can usefully reverse your sort (`sort -ur`) before giving them to your `for` loop, as then at least an `rmdir` won't fail just because there is an empty subdir you have not yet removed. You can apply `dirname` to your list of dirs to get the parent dirs, and so on in a loop until the remaining dir is `.`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -type d -empty -delete -print
```

Can remove -print to not get list of deleted directories.

Edit: If you do not want to remove the "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" directory itself, add -mindepth:

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete -print
```

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten about these find built-ins. `-delete` implies `-depth`, so you can even remove that arg.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly this command does? Does it delete the specified directory in it does not contain any files? What about if it contains child empty directories?

Comment: Read this as "find and delete all directories that are empty, depth-first search".  It will delete the "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" directory if it is empty (after all other stuff deleted) - see "Edit" above.

The -delete option implies -depth, so it will first delete any empty child directories, and will then delete resulting empty directories.